# How to set mapi properties FHaveWrittenTracking & UnifiedTracking

Tags: outlook, mapi

Can someone tell how to set mapi properties FHaveWrittenTracking & UnifiedTracking? And what are there property values?

Comment: Neither is documented. Why do you need them?

Comment: Where did you find them?